# Manage document title in React project

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I'm trying to find a library similar to `react-helmet` to manage document title. The current version of `react-helmet` doesn't work with React18. By any chance, do you know any alternative to `react-helmet` that is up-to-date? Thank you

Comment: Are you wanting to change the document title dynamically? You can manually set the document title in the html in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of how to set the title in a useEffect. You can manually set the document.title = "title" or what ever you like.

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "New Title";
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will still have the default "React App" while loading the document. Go into the public folder, index.html and change the default React App to what you want the default to be.